# CMake Include Directories Collision

Tags: c++, cmake

In my project, I have two versions of the same system library: `SysLib1.0` and `SysLib2.0`. These two libraries are used by other components of the system heavily.

`SysLib1.0` headers are located in some directory: `/project/include`. Here's an example of the contents of the project include directory:

```
/project/include/syslib/
/project/include/awesomelib/
/project/include/coollib/
```

So naturally, in CMake, other components use `include_directories(/project/include)` to gain access to system and other component headers. C++ source code could access the headers like so:

```
#include <syslib/importantheader.hpp>
```

`SysLib2.0` is installed in a *separate* location in order to avoid linking issues. `SysLib2.0`'s headers are stored here:

```
/opt/SysLib2.0/include
```

So naturally, in CMake, other components which require `SysLib2.0` use `include_directories(/opt/SysLib2.0/include)`. C++ source code could access the headers like so:

```
#include <syslib/importantheader.hpp>
```

**Now** we have run into a problem. A new component I'm writing needs access to `/project/include` in order to access `awesomelib`, **BUT** also needs `SysLib2.0`. This involves including `/opt/SysLib2.0/include` as well. Now when I say `#include <syslib/importantheader.hpp>`, that could refer to either version of the library. The compiler yells at me with some redefinition errors, as it should.

Even worse, `SysLib1.0` and `SysLib2.0` both refer to themselves as `syslib/...` when looking for headers within their own library, which is just as ambiguous.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could exclude a particular directory from an include path? Even if I am including a parent directory as shown in my example? Any solutions or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: what compiler(s) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tree-like directory structure for your project with nested CMakeLists.txt files and include separate directories in different leafs:

Given a directory structure:

```
A:
|main.cpp
|
|CMakeLists.txt
|
|B-----|
|      |CMakeLists.txt
|      |b.cpp
|
|C-----|
       |CMakeLists.txt
       |c.cpp

A/CMakeLists.txt:
    add_subdirectory(B)
    add_subdirectory(C)
    add_executable(exe main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(exe a b)

B/CMakeLists.txt:
    include_directories(/project/include)
    add_library(b b.cpp)

C/CMakeLists.txt:
    include_directories(/opt/SysLib2.0/include)
    add_library(c c.cpp)
```

This way you can include different directories for different source files; pack them up in libraries and link the final target with the libraries

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using one include path for all includes. I would rather the following structure.

```
include - your own headers
include/awesomelib
include/coollib
3rd - third party libs
3rd/syslib-1.0/include
3rd/syslib-1.0/src
3rd/syslib-2.0/include
3rd/syslib-2.0/src

src - your source
src/awesomelib (depends on syslib-1.0, includes 3rd/syslib-1.0/include)
src/coollib (depends on syslib-2.0, includes 3rd/syslib-2.0/include)
```

Then you can specify which syslib to use when building a library.